# Can you specify a different configuration for different interfaces in unbound?

Tags: linux, unbound

Can the `unbound` DNS server give different answers to DNS queries made on different interfaces (split-horizon)?

I did not see any indication in the manual that it could, but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question after figuring out how to do it in Unbound directly.

You can't (as far as I can tell) provide a completely different configuration file for different interfaces, but you can use a combination of network addresses, views and `access-control` directives to tweak some DNS answers:

```yml
server:

    # Listen on two interfaces (or use 0.0.0.0 to listen on all):
    interface: 192.168.1.1   # LAN interface
    interface: 10.0.25.1     # Other interface

    # Define access controls
    access-control: 192.168.1.1/24 allow  # LAN interface
    access-control: 10.0.25.1/24 allow    # Other interface

    # Specify custom local answers for each interface by using views:
    access-control-view: 192.168.1.1/24 lan
    access-control-view: 10.0.25.1/24 other

    # Specify default local data:
    local-data: "common.example.com. 10800 IN A 12.34.56.78"

# Custom data for LAN interface
view:
    name: "lan"
    local-data: "common.example.com. 10800 IN A 192.168.1.1"

# Custom data for Other interface
view:
    name: "other"
    local-data: "common.example.com. 10800 IN A 10.0.25.1"
```

By using this, Unbound will answer for `common.example.com`:

- 192.168.1.1 on the LAN interface
- 10.0.25.1 on the Other interface
- 12.34.56.78 on any other interface